# how to evenly space out information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, spacing

I have some vehicle information that I want to send in an email. 
I have all code working but spacing out the information is a problem. Each vehicle has a checklist and that checklist then gets emailed. So I loop through the list and get the defect and the comment.

```
foreach (var item in chkList.CheckItems)
        {
            if (item.Defect == true)
            {
                defect += item.ItemTitle + " " +  item.Comment + "\n";
            }
        }

        if (hasDefect == true)
        {
            Utils.ChecklistSendMail("Checklist", ToAddresses.Split(';'),
                "Vehicle Reg: " + reg + "\n" +
                "Checklist No: " + chkList.CheckListNo + "\n"+
                "Date: " + ChecklistDate.ToShortDateString() + "\n" +
                "Defects:                            Comments: " + "\n" + 
                defect);
        }
```

Email then looks like this:

```
Vehicle Reg: XLZ 8194
Checklist No: 0
Date: 22/03/2016
Defects:                            Comments: 
Vehicle Secure comment1
Brakes comment2
```

I want the defects and the comments to be displayed like this:

```
Defects:                     Comments: 
Vehicle Secure               comment1
Brakes                       comment2
```

How do I evenly space out the defects and the comments?

Comment: If you're using a *form* then why not use a **framework** like `bootstrap` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Format` which supports automated padding:

```
string s = string.Format("{0,-20}{1}", "hello", "world");
```

Which outputs:

```
hello               world
```

If you do that for every line, and you find a good distance (20 in my sample code), you will be fine. This all assumes the use of a mono-spaced font.

Comment: thanks for the help. I set it to a distance of 40 but the first comment has moved over more then the second. I want each row to be straight down

Comment: So, what is the problem? I am sure you made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I think the problem is `Vehicle Secure` is longer than `Lights` so it pushing the comment further out. I want all the comments to line up

Comment: @user123456789 Add your _exact_ code to your question - either you didn;t specify a long enough width or you implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: Also note that a padded "Vehicle Source" _will_ be longer than a padded "Lights" _when rendered with a proportional font_.

Comment: @DStanley the updated code is `defect += string.Format("{0,-40} {1}\n", item.ItemTitle, item.Comment);` I didn't add any code to render the string with a proportional font, but I think that's what the problem is here

Comment: So use a mono-spaced font, like `Courier New` for example.

Comment: I don't know. I don't know how you send the email. You just asked how to format it. And we helped you with that. Please ask a new question and put in all the code necessary to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Format` with the width specifier:

```
if (item.Defect == true)
{
    defect += string.Format("{0,-20} {1,-10}\n", item.ItemTitle, item.Comment);
}
```

You could also use `StringBuilder.AppendFormat` if performance becomes an issue.

If you want to *guarantee* that the columns are aligned, even with a client that uses proportional fonts, then consider rendering as HTML and using a `<table>` instead.